# Tesseract(OCR) - wrong path can't find the trained files in some devices

Tags: android, camera, directory, gallery

I am developing OCR app with LG X510 and it doesn't have a problem the location.

I got this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data file not found at ....
```

However, my other phones, Yotaphone and Huawei have the same problem with the locations.

[image]

I get the location with this:

```
datapath = getFilesDir() + "/tesseract/";
```

And it is the result of each device(LG, Yota, Huawei respectively):

```
/data/user/0/com.goodread.ocrtest2/files/tesseract//tessdata/eng.traineddata

/data/user/0/com.goodread.ocrtest2/files/tesseract//tessdata/eng.traineddata
/data/data/com.goodread.ocrtest2/files/tesseract//tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

The first one works fine. Even if it has "//"(I think the program ignores it).

How can I find the right location in each device? How can I manage it?

I believe that the `eng.traineddata` or `kor.traineddata` is in the app in all devices.

Comment: try this instead of Tesseract - https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/ or https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction. They also uses tesseract but provides api support with it which makes it easier to use.

Comment: Thanks. But they are not free. I wish I could use them!

Comment: ML Kit is free as per https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (except requests to cloud). And android's Mobile Vision is also free (if you use google cloud library by same name, then they will charge you)